# Hive - How do I pick max(Date) from Previous quarter

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, impala

I am using Hive to connect hadoop. We have daily files coming in DB. Our reporting requirement is to pick last file in previous quarter.
For e.g. If I am running report today (11 Apr), report should show data for last file loaded in march. In short we derive  Max(Date) for previous quarter.
We have table Daily_Rec with date format YYYYMMDD (string datatype) and its corresponding timestamp column YYYYMMDDHHMMSS. Any Ideas how to derive?

```
pt_version       Company     Amount
20170407140236940   ABC  0.71225691
20170408023913350   PQR  14982.3570297
20170410154948594   PQR  2059.55740225
20170411024131841   ABC  2159.557402
```

Here logic should pick of 2017-04-11 , ABC ,2159

Thanks,
CDH

Comment: Sorry example is out of synch. Last entry is 20170311024131841. Its March 11.

Comment: Hive or Impala? Not the same

Answer (score 0):

select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(pt_version,'yyyyMMddhhmmss'),
                      'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')as lastmodified,
                       company,amount from time 
                       order by lastmodified desc limit 1

change your pt_version to string..